# Prove that $(-1)^n \text{Laguerre}_n(2) \leq 1$.

Tags: laguerre-polynomials

I would like to prove the following inequalities on Laguerre polynomials evaluated at point 2:
$$
(-1)^n \text{Laguerre}_n(2) \leq 1
$$
This seems to hold numerically.
I tried to use the recurrence relation between Laguerre polynomials but I was not successful. Any ideas? I also tried expression via Bessel function $J_0$ and then contour integral but it was not successful.

Comment: This seems hard. There is a clasic bound due to Szego that in your case gives $|L_n(2)|\leq e.$

Comment: This has Szego result stated and some better results. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904506000700
But not good for the exact problem you posted.

Comment: Yes this indeed seems hard but it also seems true. I've seen those bounds but not helpful sadly.

Answer (score 7):

Theorem 8.22. on [Szego's Orthogonal polynomials](https://people.math.osu.edu/nevai.1/SZEGO/szego=szego1975=ops=OCR.pdf) the asymptotics of the Laguerre polynomials (called there Fejer's formula) looks like
$$L_n(x)=\frac{e^{x/2}}{2^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}\cdot n^{1/4}}cos \left ( 2\sqrt{nx}-\pi /4\right )+O(n^{-3/4}),\, \text{for }x>0.$$
Take $x=2,$ we have then that
$$|L_n(2)|\leq \frac{e}{2^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}}\left |\frac{cos(2^{3/2}\sqrt n-\pi /4)}{n^{1/4}} \right |+\left |O(n^{-3/4})\right |\leq 1.2896\cdot \frac{1}{n^{1/4}}+\frac{C}{n^{3/4}},$$
for some constant $C.$
Even if the constant is something big, you can check the result for small values of $n.$
Here is a graph using $C=2$ which I would say is big according to simulation:
[image]

Also, [this](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/crandall/papers/Laguerre-f.pdf) is a very good survey about the whole problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If was hoping for an analytical proof but I guess I can also rely on numerical analysis.

Comment: @Plussoyeur Not entirely sure what you mean. Fejer's formula certainly is an analytical result. So for sure, from some point $n_0$ you have your identity. Now, simulation suggests that $n_0$ is not very big, but I have not seen the proof for Fejer's. Perhaps going thru that will light in how is the asymptotic expression found.

Comment: No right I meant the tuning of C and finding $n_0$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Plot of the function]

This is a graph of $(-1)^n L_{n}^{(0)}(2)$ where $0 \leq n \leq 2500$. In this range $|(-1)^n L_{n}^{(0)}(2)| \leq 1$. This may be of interest. The [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.14#i), NIST gives $| L_{n}^{(0)}(2)| \leq e$ in equation 18.14.8 as above. Proving a better bound is probably difficult.

Comment: Indeed I don't know what more can be done. But the bound is for all $x$ so I'm sure something more can be done. Maybe some recurrence relation...

Comment: I'm calling it Plussoyeur's Conjecture,

Comment: A bounty of 50 reputation is available on Math Stack Exchange for anyone able to solve the Plussoyeur's Conjecture. Is it attractive enough?

Comment: Remind me to give you this bounty if no one provides an answer by tomorrow...

Comment: What was the context for the question? An answer would be a proof. According to Wikipedia, $(-1)^{n-i} L_{n-i}(x)$ where $0 \leq i \leq n$ is a Sturm Chain which may be relevant.

Comment: Rather complicated. Comes from an infinite linear program. I found an analytical solution provided this holds. What do you mean "an answer would be a proof" ?

Comment: Simply that the question stated "I would like to prove .." . That context is unexpected.

Comment: No proof sadly but at least the bounty did not disappear in the air.

Comment: Thanks for an intriguing problem. I will still think about solving it. The bounty is appreciated, and Phicar provided more precise information.

Comment: I hesitated with Phicar but then he has so much reputation already. Felt you needed it more.